# Find out memory usage of specific service/application in powershell?

Tags: powershell, memory, taskmanager

I'm trying to find a way to use powershell to get the memory footprint of a specific application on my machine. I want this memory to be the same memory amount listed from task-manager.

Ive been using power shell to get at some of this information. but the memory being returned does not seem to match up and I'm not sure if I'm not including some other memory usage or if the units are off.

Powershell list 3 types of memory, Working set, Pageable and non-Pageable but I'm not sure which of these comprises the task manager memory.

```
$id = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE 'WinDefend'" | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessId

$process = Get-Process -Id $id
```

Should I be adding these memory amounts up?

Is there a better way to return the task manager memory as list for the application?

The application in question is a local service server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Working set is what you're normally looking for.

Comment: You are likely looking for `Get-Counter` to access the performance counters for the service in question.